# Which algorithm will be best for Multi-label image classification

Tags: tf.keras, multilabel-classification, image-classification

I'm training data for detecting the damage of the car to calculate it's damage amount. I got upto 1000 image dataset and 5 labels.

I found a algorithm which algorithm is suitable for this use case which is CNN using keras. But in the result data it returns all the label and its confidence. It does not eliminates the labels that are not present.

I can filter the result using any threshold. But is there any algorithm that is available which will eliminate the labels that are not present and provide only labels that are available in the image?